# setting id of the hidden field array

Tags: jquery

How can I set the VALUE of the hidden field array inside

```
   $('#addbutton').click(function () {
        var txt = "<tr id='divs'><td><input type='hidden' id='hids[]' name='hifld' /> </td></tr> ";
        $('#systemconfig').append(txt);

        var dd = $("#hid").attr("value");
        var inthidden = parseInt(dd);
        var vl = parseInt(dd, '0') + 1;
        $("#hids[]").attr("value", vl); // this is not working
```

Comment: ID attribute must be unique, `name="hids[]"` would be valid but not in the case of ID attribute because ID's must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id cannot be as array, your name can be..

so your id should be like `hids` and your name like `hifld[]` and then assign the value like

```
$("#hids").val(vl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try .val() instead:

```
$("#hids[]").val( v1 )
```